# Popup - It should load an .aspx page

Tags: magnific-popup

I am using the magnific popup but i need to load an login aspx page which will contain the userid and password textboxes. I am not able to do this because when ever i click on the textboxes the popup disappears.

is there any sample where I can look to?

thanks
venkat.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
       <script>
            $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
                type: 'ajax',

                closeOnBgClick: false,
                alignTop: true,
                overflowY: 'scroll'

            });
        </script>
```